# Unable to trigger eventlistener in VisualForce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

I have a VisualForce page as below:

**VFPage1:** (https://ap5.visual.force.com/apex/VFPage1)

```
<apex:page controller="Sampleclasscontroller" >
<apex:pageBlock title="Hello {!$User.FirstName}!">
    This is your new page for the {!name} controller.
</apex:pageBlock>
<script>
    window.opener.postMessage("sample" , "*"); 
</script>
</apex:page>
```

Controller for the above page is shown below:

**Sampleclasscontroller:**

```
global class Sampleclasscontroller
 {
  public String getName() {
  String message = System.currentPagereference().getParameters().get('msg');
  if(message == 'luck')
    {
        message = 'success';           
        }
  else{
        message = 'failure';
     }
  return message;
}
}
```

In VFPage1, I get the 'msg' parameter through the URL of the page.I want the **window.opener.postMessage("sample" , "*")** statement to execute only if the 'msg' parameter of the URL is equal to "luck" i.e I want the event to be triggered only if the VFPage1 URL loaded in the browser is https://ap5.visual.force.com/apex/VFPage1?msg=luck

If any other value is passed in the 'msg' parameter in the URL, I do not want the event to be triggered.

The event is then listened by VFPage2 as shown below and the actions to be performed after triggering the event are described in VFPage2. I have added an eventListener to VFPage2 as well.

**VFPage2:**

```
<apex:page>
<style>
    .hasMotif {
        margin : 0px;
    }
</style>
<apex:iframe src="https://3d-ipsemi-dev-ed--c.ap5.visual.force.com/apex/kkvfpage" height="500" width="300" frameborder="false"/>
<script src="/support/api/40.0/lightning/opencti_min.js"></script>
<script>
   function receiveMessage(event) {
    if(event.data == 'sample') {
        var fromNumber = '3125616295';                       
        sforce.opencti.runApex({ apexClass: 'RCPhoneHelper', methodName: 'searchContact', methodParams: 'phone=' +fromNumber,
                                callback: function(response) {
                                    if(response.success == true) {
                                        var contact = response.returnValue.runApex;
                                        if(contact !== null) {
                                            sforce.opencti.screenPop({type: sforce.opencti.SCREENPOP_TYPE.SOBJECT,params: { recordId: contact.Id }});
                                            window.open('https://www.google.com/search?q=' + contact.Name);
                                        }
                                    }
                                } 
                               });
        }
    }
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);

</script>
</apex:page>
```

But the event is not getting triggered and no action is being performed in VFPage2. Don't know why. Can someone tell me what is wrong with this?

I have been desperately trying this since 2 days but got no results.
I have also referred all documentations related to event handling in Salesforce. But I'm not able to find an answer.

**PLEASE NOTE: I want VFPage1 to trigger the event defined in VFPage2 and not vice versa**

Comment: Window.opener is new to me so I apologize if I'm wrong; however, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/opener seems to imply that window.opener is a reference to the window that opened the current window. This means that it wont work unless VFPage1 is actually opened by VFPage2 but I don't see any code in your VFPage2 to suggest this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

I believe my comment has the answer but I'm extending it here with a test:

Original Comment:

> Window.opener is new to me so I apologize if I'm wrong; however,
>   developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/opener seems to imply
>   that window.opener is a reference to the window that opened the
>   current window. This means that it wont work unless VFPage1 is
>   actually opened by VFPage2 but I don't see any code in your VFPage2 to
>   suggest this is happening.

I made a SUPER simple VF page:

```
<apex:page controller="testPageController">
    <script>
    window.opener.postMessage("Hello World!", "*");
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Then I previewed the page in the dev console to get the URL. For the purposes of this demo, we'll use <url>

Then I navigated to a different visualforce page in the same org and opened up the javascript dev console in chrome (f12) and entered the following:

```
window.addEventListener("message", function(){console.log('hello world!')}, false);
window.open('<url>');
```

And upon page load my console showed "hello world" proving that it listened to the event.

This proves that it works in visualforce. The issue is most likely that the child page is not actually being opened by the parent page.

You can test this by adding `window.open('URL FOR VFPAGE 1');` right after you add the event listener.

### Update

If you can't use window.open, I found this on StackOverflow that seems to be related to your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13334204/how-can-i-send-an-event-from-child-window-to-its-parent-window

Please note, this Q/A board is for SF. StackOverflow is better suited for generic javascript questions.

Comment: Hey @gNerb. Thanks for that. But I have already tried this and it works. The method you have suggested first opens the other page using window.open, and in the other page it triggers the event in the opener page through window.opener.postmessage(). But what I actually need is that I want the event in VFPage2 to be triggered directly from VFPage1 without having to open VFPage1 from VFPage2 and then trigger the event.

Comment: @Aishu Please see my update in my answer